# HTML5, File API and jQuery posting image

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html

I have a form that I show in a dialog, and it has a "submit" button that when clicked uses jQuery to post the form to the server using AJAX. This is to an MVC action method. The uploaded file was always null. Upon using Google, I read that you cannot normally post files using AJAX unless you use some sort of plugin.

I did not wish to use a plugin and I read that this could be done with browsers that support the HTML5 File API, so I would like to get it working with this.

I do not care about drag and drop or anything else at the moment, I only want to post up the file along with the rest of the form using jQuery.

So far I have:

This is the partial view for the form:

```
@model ImageReceiptLineModel

@using (Html.BeginForm(MVC.EditImageReceiptLine(), FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
  @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ReceiptLineSetID)
  @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.LineNumber)
  <input id="uploadFile" name="uploadFile" type="file" value="Choose New Image" />
  @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ImageDescription)
  @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ImageDescription)
}
```

This is the jQuery for the sending of the form

```
if ($Form.valid()) {
        // get the url and the form data to send the request
        var Url = $Form.attr('action');
        var FormData = $Form.serialize();

        // now do the ajax call
        $.ajax({
            url: Url,
            data: FormData,
            type: 'POST',
            cache: 'false',
            success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                // do something here
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                // do something here
            }
        });
    }
```

Here is the MVC action method:

```
/// <summary>
/// Edit receipt line action
/// </summary>
/// <returns>Action result</returns>
[HttpPost]
public virtual ActionResult EditImageReceiptLine(HttpPostedFileBase uploadFile, ImageReceiptLineModel model)
{

}
```

What do I need to add to this to add the file to the form? "FormData" is the serialised form data that I post to the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a [`guide`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_files_from_web_applications#Example.3A_Uploading_a_user-selected_file) about the File API that could be used to upload files. But don't forget that this won't work on IE9. If you need to support such browsers you could use hidden iframes to simulate uploading files with AJAX. That's why plugins such as [jquery.form](http://www.malsup.com/jquery/form/) exist. In order to make it a single line of code so that you don't have to worry about browser support and stuff:

```
if ($Form.valid()) {
    // get the url and the form data to send the request
    $Form.ajaxSubmit({
        success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            // do something here
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            // do something here
        }
    });
}
```

---

UPDATE:

As requested in the comments section here's how you could use the File API.

Let's suppose that you have the following form:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(MVC.EditImageReceiptLine(), null, FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ReceiptLineSetID)
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.LineNumber)
    <input id="uploadFile" name="uploadFile" type="file" value="Choose New Image" />
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ImageDescription)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ImageDescription)    
}
```

and some link that will trigger the form submission:

```
<a href="#" id="upload">Upload the file using HTML5 File API</a>
```

Now in a js file you could have the following:

```
$('#upload').click(function () {
    if (!window.FileReader) {
        // the browser doesn't support the File API - there's no need
        // to continue;
        alert('To use this functionality please use a modern browser');
        return;
    }

    var $form = $('form');
    var uri = $form.action;
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var fd = new FormData();

    $form.find(':input').each(function () {
        if ($(this).is('input[type="file"]')) {
            var files = $(this)[0].files;
            if (files.length > 0) {
                fd.append(this.name, files[0]);
            }
        } else {
            fd.append(this.name, $(this).val());
        }
    });

    xhr.open('POST', uri, true);
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
            // handle response.
            alert(xhr.responseText); 
        }
    };

    xhr.send(fd);
});
```

Comment: thanks for the comment. I have no such issues with older browsers, it is a business app and I can make minimum requirements to be IE10 etc. I want to keep the number of external plugins to a minimum, and I also want to steer away from things like iframes etc

Comment: Alright, IE10 supports the File API. So go ahead and implement the code as shown in the guide: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_files_from_web_applications#Example.3A_Uploading_a_user-selected_file. You could also implement things like progress indicators and all kind of fancy stuff.

Comment: That's the bit I am having trouble with...integrating that sort of code into my code above that uses jQuery to post to an MVC action, not only posting the image but also the model for the rest of the form.

Comment: You are saying that you are having troubles with the code but you are not actually showing what have you tried. So I guess you are waiting for someone else write the code for you. Is this the case? I will write it for you, just wanted to see what efforts you have already put into solving this.

Comment: Ah ok, thanks! I actually assumed that I would do it a different way to the File API documentation, as I was using jQuery which hides all the request object work. I thought it would be something as simple as catching my jQuery ajax submit, and amending the formdata it already had to only add the file to what was already there. Hence why I wasn't sure how to integrate the code. But I will give this a go just now thanks.

Comment: Super, this sends it up to the server perfectly! Marked as answer. Although I still want to figure out if I can do it using the jQuery.ajax() method, but this will work for now. Cheers Darin.

Comment: No, you can't do it with jQuery.ajax. As I have already explained in my answer this method doesn't support uploading files.

Comment: Ah ok, I thought there may have been a way to piggy back on it, no problem, cheers.