# AJAX and Javascript: program leaves main page at form submission

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-validate

I'm just learning AJAX, so bear with me.  I'm putting together a small program using AJAX that adds and retrieves information to and from a database using an HTML/Javascript file and a PHP file.  I've tried several renditions but am not having any luck getting the page to stay on the main page and just resetting the form with a message indicating error or success.  The PHP file is set up using mysqli to process the submission of a text field and a file and then echo that message.  I'm using JQuery Cookbook as a guide for my latest version, but still the main page leaves and opens the PHP file in the browser, which of course is blank.  However, it is adding a new row to the database, so at least that's working.

I'm using PHPStorm and Firebug.  Any thoughts on why my code isn't working?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.validate.js"></script>
    <script>
        $('addForm').validate();
        $('addForm').submit(function(event){
            event.preventDefault();

            $('input[name="usingAJAX"]', this).val('true');
            var $this=$(this);
            var url=$this.prop('action');
            var dataToSend = $this.serialize();
            var callback = function(dataReceived) {
                $this.hide();
                //result message
                $('body').append(dataReceived)
            };
            var typeOfDataToReceive = 'html';
            $.get(url, dataToSend, callback, typeOfDataToReceive)
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="addForm" action="addActorInfo.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="hidden" name="usingAJAX" value="false"/>
        <label for="aname">Actor Name: </label>
        <input type="text" name="aname" id="aname" class=required/>
        <br>
        <br>
        <label for="aimage">Actor Photo: </label>
        <input id="aimage" type="file" name="aimage" class="required">
        <br>
        <br>
        <input type="submit" value="ADD"/>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `$('#addForm')`? (the hash indicates that it's looking for an id)

Comment: I don't think you can do an XHR with a "file" `<input>` that way.

Comment: Try to add an return false at the end of your .submit() method, this stops the form  submitting

Comment: @TobSpr there's already a call to `.preventDefault()` - I think the issue is that the code isn't running at all.

Comment: ( I don't believe to event.preventDefault)

Comment: Yeah, this seems to be the issue

Comment: @TobSpr I don't see this issue here: http://jsfiddle.net/heheL/ And why don't you trust in `preventDefault`?

Comment: @Dan Lee I tried that and the program stopped updating the database.  It's very strange because now the old version no longer inserts into the database either.

Comment: @user1852050 Check your Firebug Network tab, is the AJAX request fired? Do you get any response? Also try debugging with some `console.log` statements (and the help of Firebug)

Comment: @Dan Lee There is a GET request showing in the Firebug Newtwork tab.  I would think that should be a POST though?

Comment: @user1852050 it would be a POST if you had included `method=POST` in your `<form>` tag.

Comment: @user1852050 ... and it's not updating the database anymore because you can't post a "file" input with XHR. (Well, you can, but not that way.)

Comment: @Pointy I actually had it working prior to making a change suggested above.  It submitted two rows into my database.  But why is this way not appropriate?  More importantly, what would be more appropriate?

Answer (score 1):

A few issues.

- Your form's selector, `$('addForm')`, is missing the `#` as everyone is pointing out.
- You're missing the `$(document).ready()` function since your `form` does not yet exist when the JavaScript is called, this is required.
- You don't need another `submit` handler since the jQuery Validate plugin has a [`submitHandler` callback function](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#toptions) built in.  [As per docs](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#toptions), *"The right place to submit a form via Ajax after it validated."*

Something like this:

(assuming that the OP's `.ajax` function is already correct.)

```
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#addForm').validate({
        //other options,
        submitHandler: function (form) {

            // your ajax code

            return false;  // <-- stop form redirection since you used ajax
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for being so helpful :). I tried your suggestions, but have a string of errors returned.  It doesn't appear that anything is being passed to the php file because the code there is coming up empty.  The errors include an Undefined index for aname and aimage, an error on fopen() because the filename is empty and fread() and fclose().

Comment: My answer only shows how to use `ajax` with the Validate plugin, and assumes that your `ajax` function is correct and working.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  The ajax was partially working just before I posted this question.  It inserted two records successfully, but left the page.  I'm uncertain why it is no longer.  Do you see any specific problems?

Comment: I changed the instances of `this` into `form`... but I have no way to test your code.

Answer (score 1):

There are several problems, most discussed in comments already:

- Your selector when you set up the "submit" handler was wrong. It should have been `$('#addForm')`
- You're trying to use `$.get()` to process a form that includes a "file" `<input>` element. That can't be done.

To upload a file, you can either:

1. POST your form (has to be POST, not GET) and give it a "target" attribute of a hidden `<iframe>` element on the page.  The response from the server should include JavaScript to update the parent page (the page with the form on it) as appropriate.
2. Use the HTML5 File API to grab the file contents and then upload via XHR.  I've never tried to do this, but [here is an older SO question about it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12515494).

Comment: Ah, I see where I need to change $.get() to $.post.  Adding some html for a target attribute is easy enough.  How would I code that in Javascript?

Comment: Edit that.  I just checked in PHPStorm about replacing $.get() with $.post() and it's not defined.  I have jquery and jquery.validate included.  Is $.post() available in another library?  If not, how else might I be able to code this?

Comment: @user1852050 Before you fixed your selector (the "addForm" problem), your form was being posted to the server by browser using its ordinary native posting mechanism. That's why the page was being overwritten. Your `$.get()` had nothing to do with that :-)